# How to derive $x$ w.r.t $p(\vert x\vert\le \vert a - f\vert\ , \vert x \vert\le \vert b - f\vert)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

How to derive the following probability in a close form formula with respect to $x$?
\begin{equation}
p(\vert x\vert\le \vert a - f\vert\  , \vert x \vert\le \vert b - f\vert)
\end{equation}
where $f \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $a$,$b$ are constant.

At first glance I thought it can be derived by from a MultiVariate [Folded Normal distribution (MVFN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution). However, it seems the cummlative probability function(CDF) of MVFN is a non trivial thing and even the some recent work[1][2] on MVFN didn't mention about this(please correct me if I missed some significant part).

I am not a mathematical researcher but I wonder if I can leverage the fact that actually the probability is only governed by one distribution of $f$, but failed myself. What's more I really don't want to sample this probability.

Could Anyone give me some hint?

---

[1] Chakraborty, Ashis Kumar, and Moutushi Chatterjee. "On multivariate folded normal distribution." Sankhya B 75.1 (2013): 1-15.
[2] Murthy, G.S.R. A Note on Multivariate Folded Normal Distribution. Sankhya B 77, 108–113 (2015) doi:10.1007/s13571-014-0092-9

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: So $f$ is a random variable but $x, a, b$ are all just constants?  You can simply find the range of $f$ that satisfies the condition, as a function of $x, a, b$.  You are looking at either $2$ or $3$ ranges in the real life, and you can evaluate the probability using the CDF of normal variables.

Comment: @antkam Indeed! many thanks, I should have thought about this earlier...

Comment: @Naofumi - ha, you're welcome.  Perhaps this was an example of "over-thinking" on your part? :)